# how do I force this a tag to be circular?

Tags: css

I've got an icon within a link tag and I'm trying to make it circular, but it fits to the content rather than being set by my width and height settings. Here's what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMlMQ.png

My code is like this:

html:

```
<div class="small-4 columns switchButton">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-bolt"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

And my CSS is like this:

```
.switchButton
    text-align: center
    margin: 60px 0 60px 0
.switchButton a
    text-decoration: none
    width: 80px
    height: 80px
    font-size: 40px
    padding: 20px
    -moz-border-radius: 40px
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px
    border-radius: 40px
```

The icon is by font-awesome and has the following CSS:

```
a [class^="icon-"], a [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline;
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline;
width: auto;
height: auto;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: baseline;
background-image: none;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 0;
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

So, even though the width and height are set, it still fits to the icon. Any ideas?

Relevant JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/babaggeii/QZSwn/2/ - you can see that the a tag fits the text rather than the dimensions specified.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587814/how-do-i-prevent-an-image-from-overflowing-a-rounded-corner-box-with-css3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248734/css3-border-radius-clipping-issues possible duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure those are directly relevant to this question.

Comment: Can you post on JSFiddle?

Comment: Thanks, I've added one to the main text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like isn't your `a` — it has `60px` x `87px` and does not correspond with what you put in CSS.

Try this:

```
.switchButton a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;

    /** My CSS **/
    display: block; /* The element is displayed as a block-level element (like paragraphs and headers) */
    line-height: 80px; /* To determine the height of your line */
    text-align: center; /* To centralize the text horizontally */
}
```

I have illustrated the code above on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/QZSwn/4/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a JSFiddle to the main text.